# How to ask make to not always re-create files depending on .PHONY targets?

Tags: make

I have this:

```
.PHONY: check
check:
    script-returning-nearly-always-zero

obj2.img: obj1.img check
    make-obj2-from-obj1
```

So, logic is that I want to re-generate `obj2.img`, if it is older as obj1 (or it does not even exist). However, I want an error if the "check" target fails.

Now my problem is that the generator of `obj2.img` always runs. I think, it might be because `check` is `.PHONY`.

Can I somehow ask make to re-generate `obj2.img` only if `obj1.img` is newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to *not* have [`check` as a prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time `make` considers that file.

Instead, invoke `check` as a Make target explicitly:

```
obj2.img: obj1.img
    $(MAKE) check
    make-obj2-from-obj1
```

Thus, if `obj2.img` exists and is not older than `obj1.img`, it won’t be remade; otherwise, first the check will run, and then if that succeeds, `make-obj2-from-obj1`.

This also has the side benefit that you can force a rebuild even if the check fails, using the `-k` option.